# Why can't I read a JSON file on Vercel when using Next.js SSR?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

I have a barebones Next.js project consisting of three main files (listed below) where I'm trying to generate the index page with data from a JSON file. If I deploy the project to Vercel using getStaticProps, everything works properly.

However, when I deploy using getServerSideProps, the project builds but I get "500: Internal Server Error" when visiting the site and an error message (also listed below) in Vercel's Functions logs. I can run the app in development and deployment modes using getServerSideProps locally, just not on Vercel.

Why is the project able to find the JSON file when deployed to Vercel while using getStaticProps, but not getServerSideProps?

pages/index.tsx:

```js
import { GetStaticProps, GetServerSideProps } from 'next';
import { User, getUsers } from '../lib/users';

// export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async () => {
    const users = await getUsers();
    return { props: { users } };
};

export default function Home({ users }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {users.map((user: User) => (
                <p key={user.id}>{user.name}</p>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

lib/users.ts:

```js
import fs from 'fs';

export interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

export function getUsers(): User[] {
    const users = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('data/users.json').toString());
    return users;
}
```

data/users.json:

```json
[
    { "id": 1, "name": "Alice" },
    { "id": 2, "name": "Bob" },
    { "id": 3, "name": "Charlie" }
]
```

Vercel's Functions log:

```
[GET] /
09:41:25:73
2022-03-11T17:41:26.362Z    c8febc98-491a-4433-a2af-6dd7be25b040    ERROR   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'data/users.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:497:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:393:35)
    at getUsers (/var/task/.next/server/pages/index.js:28:52)
    at getServerSideProps (/var/task/.next/server/pages/index.js:40:25)
    at Object.renderToHTML (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/render.js:566:26)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async doRender (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:855:38)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:950:28
    at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache.js:63:36 {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'data/users.json',
  page: '/'
}
RequestId: c8febc98-491a-4433-a2af-6dd7be25b040 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that data folder place in public folder.

```
public
 data
   user.json
pages
styles
```

and put a slash inside fs.readFileSync

```
export function getUsers(): User[] {
const users = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/data/users.json').toString());
return users;
}
```

Your JSON must be like this:

```
{
"users" : [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Alice" },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Bob" },
 { "id": 3, "name": "Charlie" }
]
}
```

Comment: i got error on local when using this, any solution?

Comment: @mamenatech what is your Next.js version?

Comment: @mamenatech I will post another answer, please check if it worked please do not forget to accept and vote.

Comment: Solved, see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/75887034/12771945

Answer (score 1):

i hope this help to read file using process.cwd()

```
import fse from "fs-extra"
import path from "path"


 const filePath = path.join(process.cwd(), "firebaseServiceAccount.json")

     fse.readFile(filePath, 'utf-8', async (error, data) => {
     
      const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

     })
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of reading the `JSON` data on the server-side like `getServerSideProps` function.

1. create a folder called `data` at the root of the project and put the `JSON` file in the directory.
2. Then on the page where you have `getServerSideProps` you can import file like this.

   ```
   export async function getServerSideProps(){
     // path to the JSON file
     const staticData = await import('../../../data/index.json').then((res) => res.default);
     console.log("Json data" , staticData);
     return {
        props : {
           data : staticData || null
         }
      }
   }
   ```

Then check the console you should see the response as an object.

[image]

You can also do this like separate function like in the previous answer just make sure the file is in root not in public and change the function to async function.

```
export async function getUsers(): User[] {
 const users = await import('../data/index.json').then((res) => res.default);
   return users;
}
```

and in getServerSideProps just import the function and call it from there.